# How to pass variables with Android fragmentmanager

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have the following simple code to switch from one fragment to another in the content frame. Is there a simple way to pass variables in the following code?

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();

fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new TransactionDetailsFragment()).commit();
```

Comment: No idea why this was marked as dupe, this question clearly says fragmentmanager, the cited answer refers only to a new fragment class., which for a java newb makes a diff. However the accepted answer seems to have acknowledged this correctly.

Comment: Great question, this was exactly what I was looking for, much differently from the "duplicate" marked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Bundle:

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
arguments.putInt("VALUE1", 0);
arguments.putInt("VALUE2", 100);

MyFragment myFragment = new Fragment();
fragment.setArguments(arguments);

fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, myFragment).commit();
```

Then, you retrieve as follows:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            int value1 = bundle.getInt("VALUE1", -1);
            int value2 = bundle.getInt("VALUE2", -1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use the newInstance method - create a method inside your Fragment class like:

```
 public static TransactionDetailsFragment newInstance(String param) {
    TransactionDetailsFragment frag = new TransactionDetailsFragment();
    Bundle bund = new Bundle();
    bund.putString("paramkey", param); // you use key to later grab the value
    frag.setArguments(bund);
    return frag;
}
```

So to create your fragment you do:

```
TransactionDetailsFragment.newInstance("PASSING VALUE");
```

(This is used instead of your `new TransactionDetailsFragment()` )

Then for example in onCreate/onCreateView of the same fragment you get the value like this:

```
String value = getArguments().getString("paramkey");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a parameterized constructor for `TransactionDetailsFragment`?

```
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new TransactionDetailsFragment(YOUR_PARAMS)).commit();
```

When you create `new TransactionDetailsFragment(YOUR_PARAMS)` as a param of `FragmentTransaction`, I think using constructor is a good choice.

Comment: Using this, but it has a problem -- without noarg constructor, this fragment cant be used in xml layout.