# Can I limit setText to within the scope of an individual fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app, I have multiple instances of the same fragment, `ActivityFragment`. In each fragment, there is an `activity_text` textview. When the fragment is added to the layout, I want to set the `activity_text` textview within that fragment during `onCreate`. However, when I try to do this, every `ActivityFragment` onscreen will have their `activity_text` textview changed.

Is there any way that I can limit `setText` to within the scope of an individual fragment without using unique Tags or IDs for each fragment?

Here is my ActivityFragment class:

```
public static class ActivityFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View fragment1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment, container, false);

        final TextView activityText = (TextView) fragment1.findViewById(R.id.activity_text);
        //Calling setText changes the activityText Textview in every fragment onscreen
        activityText.setText(text);


        return fragment1;
    }
}
```

Here is my MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    Static String text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        for (int i = 0; i != 5; i++) {
            //This ensures each fragment receives a unique String
            text = "success" + i;
            ActivityFragment myFragment = new ActivityFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on your question? What exactly do mean by " limit setText to within the scope of an individual fragment"? You can override methods like **onAttach** on **onDetach** do deal with the moment that the fragment gets attached. You can also **send data through bundle** for each fragment. Is that what you want?

Comment: @VictorNeves As per the answers provided, I should be passing data to the fragment through a Bundle. Sorry for the confusing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's two problems with your code.

The first is that you're using a `static String text` to transmit information from your Activity to your Fragments. In general, this is not a good idea; if you need to "pass" something from your Activity to your Fragment at the time it's constructed, you should use `Fragment.setArguments(Bundle)` to do that.

The second is that you seem to have a misconception about the timing of `FragmentTransaction`s. Your `for` loop changes the value of `text` and then `.commit()`s a new fragment five times. But these transactions are asynchronous, and the fragment lifecycle has its own timeline. So your `onCreateView()` will actually wind up being called after your activity `onCreate()` has finished, and so each of your five fragments gets the same value from `text`.

Here's how I'd solve it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        for (int i = 0; i != 5; i++) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("text", "success" + i);

            ActivityFragment myFragment = new ActivityFragment();
            myFragment.setArguments(args);

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment).commit();
        }
    }

    public static class ActivityFragment extends Fragment {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View fragment1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment, container, false);

            final TextView activityText = (TextView) fragment1.findViewById(R.id.activity_text);
            String text = getArguments().getString("text");
            activityText.setText(text);

            return fragment1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue have nothing to do with the scope of the textview.
Each fragment is individually setting the textView to `text`, as you instructed them to do so. That happens because onCreateView gets called much latter, after all the fragment transactions happened.

On your code you put the comment: `//This ensures each fragment receives a unique String`, actually, there's nothing there ensuring that fragments are receiving anything. I recommend you reading what a `static` means in Java. On that `for-loop` you change the value of `text` 5 times in a row and the last value is "success4".

The correct way to pass parameters to a fragment is via a `Bundle` added calling the methong `setArguments(Bundle)`

I searched and this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35737232/906362 shows very well explained how to do that. The gist is something like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i != 5; i++) {
        ActivityFragment myFragment = new ActivityFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        // This really ensures each fragment receives a unique String
        b.putString("text", "success" + i)
        myFragment.setArguments(b);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment).commit();
    }
```

and then to get this value on the fragment:

```
  TextView activityText = (TextView) fragment1.findViewById(R.id.activity_text);
  activityText.setText(getArguments().getString("text");
```