# How to update listView within the same activity?

Tags: android, list, surfaceview

Activity A wants to update a listView inside the same activity. 
Value is received from a surfaceview - scan, it should not update the listView until the finish button is pressed.

Comment: why here you want to 'call' same activity? you need to update  the listview while you are in the same activity ?

Comment: In Activity A there is a surfaceview which has camera opened for scanning qrcodes. I need to scan qrcode continuously and store the result each time into the list until finish button pressed.

Comment: ok, you need to use a callback on scancomplete each time and you have to use a thread to update the listview - notifydatasetchange.

Comment: Getting an error like...   Exception thrown from receiver. java.lang.illegalstateexception:Detection processor must first be set with setprocessor in order to get Detection results.

Comment: can you add code and logs here to understand more

Answer (score 0):

you can use fragments in your activity and then use fragment manager to navigate between your camera page and the listView page.

you can use bundles to share data between these two fragments.

use this to learn more about fragments:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

and for sharing data between fragments visit this:
[How to pass variables with Android fragmentmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737141/how-to-pass-variables-with-android-fragmentmanager)